# Probability - number of combinations of an ordered list, elements can be removed

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given the ordered list of elements, e.g. [1,2,3,4,5] I would like to get the number of possible combinations given that elements can be removed from the list, but their order doesn't change.

[1,2,3,4,5] could have at least those combinations
[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [2,3,4,5], [4,5], [1], [2] etc.

Ideally I would get the formula allowing me to get the total value for any size list.

Where to start?

Comment: Is $[2,5]$ allowed? $[1,2,3,4,5]$? $[\,]$?

Comment: Thanks for the precision. It is allowed.

Comment: Then $2^n$ looks sensible.  Or $2^n-2$ if you exclude my second and third questions

Comment: If @Henry is correct and [2,5] is allowed, then there is a 1-1 bijection between ordered subsets of the ordering [1,2,3,4,5] and subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Since there are $2^5$ subsets of a 5-element set, there are $2^5$ of your orderings (or $2^5-2$ proper non-empty subsets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it, either you remove $1$ or you don't. Thus there are $2$ options here. Similarly, either you remove $2$ or you don't, and this is independent of whether we remove $1$ or not. Thus there are $2\times2=4$ ways to do $1$ and $2$. Similarly, for $1,2,3$ there are $2^3$ ways, etc. so for $1,2,3,4,5$ there are $32$ ways overall.

If you don't allow the empty list, then decrease this value by $1$, and if you have to remove at least one element, then decrease by $1$ (perhaps again).